# How to get id of dynamically loaded data in static method which is present in textbox?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server

i'm trying to get the id of the data present in text box which is dynamically loaded
my problem is i have a text box which acts as search box and loads data on key press the code is here

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string[] GetCustomers(string prefix)
    {
        leadsmg ld = new leadsmg();

        List<string> customers = new List<string>();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PO-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=leadsp;User ID=sa;Password=123;");          
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select cname,cid  from companydet where cname like @SearchText + '%'";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefix);
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    customers.Add(string.Format("{0}-{1}", sdr["cname"], sdr["cid"]));



                }
            }
            conn.Close();

        }

        return customers.ToArray();

    }
```

and based on this textbox i'm trying to load another textbox which gives all the workers of that perticular company, so i need the id form the previous text box

the code for next text box to dynamically load data is

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string[] GetContactPerson(string prefix)
    {
        leadsmg ld = new leadsmg();
        List<string> customers1 = new List<string>();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PO-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=leadsp;User ID=sa;Password=123;");

        using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd1.CommandText = "select cpid,cpfname,cplname  from contactper where (cpfname like @SearchText + '%')and cid='@Cid'";
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefix);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cid", ld.cmpnyid);//hidden field text id ,here i want to access first textbox hidden id to load data from database
            cmd1.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    customers1.Add(string.Format("{0}-{1}", sdr["cpfname"] + " " + sdr["cplname"], sdr["cpid"]));
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }

        return customers1.ToArray();
    }
```

and this is the java script i'm using in my web page

```
 $(function () {
        $("[id$=txtSearchCmpny]").autocomplete({ //textboxid
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/leadsmg.aspx/GetCustomers") %>',
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.split('-')[0],
                                val: item.split('-')[1]
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (e, i) {
                $("[id$=cmpnyid]").val(i.item.val);//hidden feild id

            },
            minLength: 1
        });
```

how can i get the id of first textbox so that i can load my second textbox ?

Comment: where you need `id` of first textbox in above JS code. Do you need it in `select:` callback?

Comment: i need id in second textbox so that i can access the data present in database